# How to get the number of rows that are not in the past

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use MySQL to collect the sum of the rows that are new in the current month but not in the past.

I have this table:

```
id, gamer_id, date
```

I want to check how many new gamers registered in the current month but there are no records for them for previous months.

How can I do this?

```
mysql_num_rows(
     mysql_query(
        "SELECT id FROM gamers WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' GROUP BY gamer_id"
     )
);
```

But here, I dont know how to do the IF, can someone please help me?

Comment: As I am not very savvy with MySQL, I would grab all the rows, then convert the date to time using `strtotime()`.  But there is probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: Since it sounds like, from your comments, this isn't your table that has the user information -- is a registered date not saved in your "users" table (or whatever you call it). That would be the most elegant solution, rather than relying on what appears to be some sort of access table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($cnt) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(
    "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `gamers` WHERE `date` >= '2012-01-01'"
));
```

In particular it's important to use backticks around your column names, because `date` is a reserved word.

**EDIT:**

I'm not really understanding your situation, it sounds like you may need to revise your database structure. Anyways, this query should be what you're looking for:

```
list($cnt) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(
    "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `gamers` WHERE MIN(`date`) >= '2012-01-01'" GROUP BY `gamer_id`
));
```

Comment: yeah but the number I will get is not good because the gamer can be in the past months also, I want the number only for NEW gamers..

Comment: So you're saying that 1) gamers can appear multiple times over different dates and 2) you only want them counted if they have no entries prior to the specified date?

Comment: what does 'gamers' table store ? Isn't it the master table for gamers where 'id' is the primary key ?